# How to import theme in Grafana when building a new panel plugin?

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I am currently trying to build a new panel plugin as a ReactJS component for my Grafana application. I am following the [official guide](https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin) and trying to display a circle that changes color according to the option set by the user.

The guide proposes the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from 'types';

interface Props extends PanelProps<SimpleOptions> {}

export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {

  let color: string;
  switch (options.color) {
    case 'red':
      color = theme.palette.redBase; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
    case 'green':
      color = theme.palette.greenBase; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
    case 'blue':
      color = theme.palette.blue95; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
  }

  return (
  <g>
    <circle style={{ fill: color }} r={100} />
  </g>
  );
};
```

However, i get a compile error (`Cannot find name 'theme'`) because there's no "theme" imported and the guide does not specify where to find it.

How can i import `theme` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `theme` can be imported from `grafana-ui` package:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from 'types';
import { useTheme } from '@grafana/ui'; // import useTheme hook

interface Props extends PanelProps<SimpleOptions> {}

export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {

  const theme = useTheme(); // invoke the hook to get the theme

  let color: string;
  switch (options.color) {
    case 'red':
      color = theme.palette.redBase; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
    case 'green':
      color = theme.palette.greenBase; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
    case 'blue':
      color = theme.palette.blue95; // <--- Cannot find name 'theme'
      break;
  }

  return (
  <g>
    <circle style={{ fill: color }} r={100} />
  </g>
  );
};
```